# Smoke render problem, transparent triangle artifact

Tags: smoke-simulation

When I render my smoke there is a triangle shape that doesn't get rendered, I heard somewhere (I can't remember where no matter how hard I google it... ) that there is a workaround involving dual smoke domains that are linked somehow.

I am fairly new to blender and rendering overall so I wouldn't be surprised if this is some basic stuff that I missed.  But I can't find any help.

[image]

[image: Camera clipping settings, the orange line is a visualization of the clipping range I think.]

Comment: Could you upload your .blend or give more information about your scene? You mention two smoke domains..

Comment: The two smoke domains are not in my scene, only mentioned as a solution somewhere on the internet. I'll try to upload my scene.

Comment: I'm not having that issue when I render. Try downloading a newer version of Blender.

Comment: Updating to latest blender did not solve it but increasing the camera clipping limit did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Camera Clipping End Distance**

One thing to check is to see if your Camera's Clipping End distance is set deep enough to render all parts of your scene. If it is set too close (i.e. to too low of a number), then anything beyond that distance (in Distance units) will not be rendered -- instead, beyond that point, your render will show only the background color, which here is transparent.

To see if this is your problem, check these 2 things:

**If this happens when rendering**

1. Select the camera
2. In the Object Properties window, click on the Camera tab
3. Increase the Clipping End to a higher number (i.e. farther distance). Here the End distance is set to 100, but you might need to set it higher:

   [image]
4. Now render again and see if all of your scene is included in the render.

**If this happens when navigating in viewport (i.e. not in camera mode or render)**
If this happens when navigating in viewport, then you have to change the clipping end in the Viewport Properties panel:

2. Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the Viewport Properties
3. Under View, set the Clip End higher:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your very thorough answer but I don't think it is camera clipping, I will add a picture of my camera settings in my question above.

Comment: And another thing is that the first few frames of the animation usually do not have the transparent triangle (if that info helps).

Comment: @Vindron The problem disappeared for me when I set the *clipping end* to 520. Does it still occur for you with the clipping end bumped up?

Comment: @gandalf3 Yes it helped. I was fooled by the visualisation thing, because that clearly goes far beyond the smoke before you set it to 520.

Comment: @Vindron The trick is it has to go past the entire domain object, not just the smoke.