# How can I see a whole object and it's boundaries?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

hi how can I change the setting so I can see the whole object. When I zoom in I see different parts of the object.

Comment: adjust the clip distance for the viewport

Comment: possible duplicates: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8195/smoke-render-problem-transparent-triangle-artifact/8203#8203 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport/8554#8554 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71182/parts-of-my-models-are-disappearing-as-my-scene-gets-bigger/71185#71185

Comment: I know @cegaton had pointed probably all BSE duplicates but you may also check out this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77515/face-was-broken-while-zoom-in